# Choosing between std::list and std::vector

Tags: c++, list, vector

I have wrote a code which tries to find the repetitions in a vector. In case of a repetition, it will add the position to a list. For example a sequence of `100 110 90 100 140 90 100` will be a 2D vector. The first dimension contains unique letters (or numbers) and a list of repetitions are appended as a second dimension. So the result looks like

```
100 -> [0 3 6]
110 -> [1]
90 -> [2 5]
140 -> [4]
```

The code is fairly simple

```
typedef unsigned long long int ulong;
typedef std::vector<ulong> aVector;
struct entry {
  entry( ulong a, ulong t ) {
    addr = a;
    time.push_back(t);
  }
  ulong addr;
  aVector time;
};

// vec contains original data
// theVec is the output vector
void compress( aVector &vec, std::vector< entry > &theVec )
{
   aVector::iterator it = vec.begin();
   aVector::iterator it_end = vec.end();
   std::vector< entry >::iterator ait;
   for (ulong i = 0; it != it_end; ++it, ++i) {  // iterate over input vector
     ulong addr = *it;
     if (theVec.empty()) {  // insert the first item
       theVec.push_back( entry(addr, i) );
       continue;
     }
     ait = find_if( theVec.begin(), theVec.end(), equal_addr(addr));
     if (ait == theVec.end()) { // entry doesn't exist in compressed vector, so insert
       theVec.push_back( entry(addr, i) );
     } else { // write down the position of the repeated number (second dimension)
       ait->time.push_back(i);
     }
   }
}
```

The find_if will look up like this

```
struct equal_addr : std::unary_function<entry,bool>
{
  equal_addr(const ulong &anAddr) : theAddr(anAddr) {}
  bool operator()(const entry &arg) const { return arg.addr == theAddr; }
  const ulong &theAddr;
};
```

Problem is, for moderate input sizes (20M for my tests), the code is very slow and it may take one day to exit the compress function. Is there any chance for speedup by using `std::list` instead of `std::vec`? Since `list` is performs better for sequential things. However I just want to know, if it can help or not. If it is useful then I have change some other codes.

Looking for any advice.

Comment: Best thing to do is to profile. You should try libstdc++ profile mode if you're running GCC. It can be enabled with `-D_GLIBCXX_PROFILE`.

Comment: I'd prefer associative containers in your case, say, `std::map<int, std::list<std::size_t>>`.

Comment: What kind of compiler optimizations are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. why don't you try it, and measure the results for yourself?
2. no, `list` does not perform better for "sequential things". It performs dramatically worse for *everything*.

The only real advantage it has is that elements in a `list` are stable and pointers/iterators to elements won't be eliminated as the list is modified or grown.

Comment: As I said, i have change some other code. So if `list` has no effect then I am happy not to changed that

Comment: @mahmood well, [this](http://bulldozer00.com/2012/02/09/vectors-and-lists/) post has some slides from Bjarne Stroustrup, showing performance of `vector` vs `list`, which you may find useful. `list` should *never* be used if you want performance.